# Release Management - Run Command Line

Tags: command-prompt, ms-release-management

I have Release Management setup to process our web application. As part of this process I have a simple command line I need to run that creates a Folder Junction within the location of the Published Application:

```
mklink /j C:\Webs\WebSite\images\Staff C:\Webs\Intranet\Images\staff
```

where **C:\Webs\WebSite\images\Staff** is where the Folder Junction will live and **C:\Webs\Intranet\Images\staff** is where the Folder Junction will point to.

If I run the above command line in command prompt it works fine.

I wishfully assumed I could just add a new Component with No Tool and put the above command line in the space where it says Command... However it always fails saying that it 'Cannot find the file specified'.

I am having trouble finding any plain examples of applying some command line to a Release Management process so am hoping someone here has already had some experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working after half a days worth of fiddling around in Release Management. Firstly, I had to create a new Tool (in Inventory). For Command I entered: **cmd** (to initiate the command prompt) and and Argument: **__ScriptToExecute__**

I then created a new Action with the same Argument as above - creating a new Category for this custom Action.

Then, In the Release template I bring in the new Action from the Tool box and add the following command line/ Powershell script:

**cmd.exe /c "mklink /j C:\Webs\WebApp\images\Staff C:\Webs\Intranet\Images\staff"**

One thing to bear in mind with my specific example is that as I am clearing out the web site location before repopulating at every stage, simply deleting this folder also results in the the contents of the Junction Folder also being deleted. To avoid this I used the Custom Action at the begining of each stage with the following command:

**start cmd.exe /c "cmd /c rmdir c:\Webs\WebApp\images\staff"**

Answer (score 1):

Release management's Command Line utility must be provided with an executable.
In this instance as MKLink is part of the windows cmd.exe library you should initiate cmd.exe with a command.

For the FilePath in Release Management you should enter: 
`cmd /c mklink /j C:\Webs\WebSite\images\Staff C:\Webs\Intranet\Images\staff`

/c runs the command and exits the cmd window. /k will run the command and leave the cmd window open.